# How to map unique groups to ids without looping

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Suppose the following numpy array

```
>>> z = np.zeros(3, dtype={'names': ("id", "dim1", "cnt1"), 'formats': ('i8', 'S3', 'u8')})
>>> z
array([(0, '', 0L), (0, '', 0L), (0, '', 0L)],
      dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('dim1', 'S3'), ('cnt1', '<u8')])
>>> z["dim1"] = ["foo", "foo", "bar"]
>>>
>>>
>>> z["cnt1"] = [1,2,3]
>>> z
array([(0, 'foo', 1L), (0, 'foo', 2L), (0, 'bar', 3L)],
      dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('dim1', 'S3'), ('cnt1', '<u8')])
```

And I want to map each unique `dim1` to an id.
One way to do it with a for loop on unique dim1 values is the following:

```
>>> unique_groups = np.unique(z["dim1"])
>>> groups = z["dim1"]
>>> for idx, ug in enumerate(unique_groups):
...     z["id"][ug == groups] = idx
...
>>> z
array([(1, 'foo', 1L), (1, 'foo', 2L), (0, 'bar', 3L)],
      dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('dim1', 'S3'), ('cnt1', '<u8')])
>>>
```

I was wondering if there is way to do it without a for loop, with a vector operation instead.
I tried to perform it with vectorizing a function like shown below

```
>>> def map_column(key):
...     return m[key]
...
>>> m
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 0}
>>> f = np.vectorize(map_column, otypes=[str])
>>> f(z["dim1"])
array(['1', '1', '0'],
      dtype='|S1')
```

Is any other more efficient way to do it ? And between the 2 ways which is considered to be better performance wise ?

Comment: Note that `np.vectorize` does nothing more than a Python loop internally. Thus, it is generally not faster than using a basic loop.

Comment: yes, I know from reading the documentation. So, I was thinking that there should be a fast way in doing a mapping like that. Perhaps with nditer on dim1 or id column ?

Comment: "And between the 2 ways which is considered to be better performance wise ?" Jerome is saying basically, neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.searchsorted()`:

```py
In [2]: unique_groups = np.unique(z["dim1"])

In [3]: z["id"] = unique_groups.searchsorted(z["dim1"])

In [4]: z
Out[4]:
array([(1, b'foo', 1), (1, b'foo', 2), (0, b'bar', 3)],
      dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('dim1', 'S3'), ('cnt1', '<u8')])
```

Not sure about performance, but probably not much better.

Comment: I think `z["id"] = np.unique(z["dim1"], return_inverse=True)[1]` should do the job too and it is simpler ;) .

Comment: The provided answers cover my case. But is there a generic solution for fill id column or replace its values with custom values and not the indexes of unique groups? I will create a new question about it with examples.